# Remote server replied: 553 Mail from 59.98.24.173 not allowed - 5.7.1 [BL21]

Tags: php

I am trying to send mail from my localhost but i get this strange error from yahoo :-

`Remote server replied: 553 Mail from 59.98.24.173 not allowed - 5.7.1 [BL21] Connections not accepted from IP addresses on Spamhaus PBL; see http://postmaster.yahoo.com/errors/550-bl21.html [550]`

I am using HmailServer. **My ip address is dynamic and everytime i reset my modem even though i have a new ip address i still get the same message from yahoo.**

I am really fed up of Yahoo. This is my code to send mail :-

```
 public static function sendMail($To , $Subject, $Body){
        $from = 'noreply@testingmylocalhost.org';
        ini_set('smtp_port',25);
        ini_set('SMTP','localhost');
        ini_set('sendmail_from',$from);
        $headers  = "From: $from\r\n";
        $headers .= "Reply-To: ". $To . "\r\n";
        $headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
        $headers .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n";
        echo mail($To, $Subject, $Body);
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Congratulations, your IP has been [blacklisted](http://postmaster.yahoo.com/errors/550-bl21.html) due to spam. Stop trying to send Yahoo! email.

Comment: But why is it blacklisted? How and when? I am just trying to send test mails from my localhost to test whether mail is being properly sent or not? I even tried it with new ip and it gets instantly blacklisted even though i send the mail very 1st time.

Comment: No, it was blacklisted long before you tried. Use an external SMTP server to send it.